# What is the meaning of the term "Ground Paddle" in the context of ORG1411 PCB design?

Tags: pcb, ground, circuit-design, gps

I am designing a breakout-board style PCB for prototyping an ORG1411-PM01 module and am unsure about how to meet the datasheet's layout recommendation for the "ground paddle"?

The *Reccomended PCB Layout* is shown below: [image: Reconmended Footprint]

The main issue is that despite the drawing showing a "ground paddle" (which I assume to be the olive green box 6.35*10.008mm), later descriptions shown in 19.3 indicate that there is not to be copper below the component aside from on the bottom layer. [image]

Key question is this: **If I am including a ground plane on the bottom layer is this in fact the "ground paddle? Or does a separate "ground paddle" have to be included?**

Any advice appreciated!

---

UPDATE Received 12/02/17

An email request to Origin asking for clarification on this issue led to me receiving another guide entitled *"HORNET modules Layout Recommendations - Application Notes"*, dated to 17th Feb 2016. This includes a clearer diagram to replace Fig. 14 from section 19.3. [image] I am unsure as to why they have not updated the main datasheet, but this update definitely helps to clarify things.

Comment: Due to low reputation I could not post a link to the main datasheet, but it can be found here: (link here: https://www.origingps.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Nano-Hornet-ORG1411-Datasheet.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording and the illustration clearly show copper on the top layer, masked with solder resist. It's required to be connected to the main ground plane with multiple vias, whichever layer that ground happens to be on.

Those multiple vias would be passing through the volume that fig 19.3 shows as copper keep out. It's potentially ambiguous, as vias are copper, but I'm sure it means copper tracks, as too many tracks would impede the placing of 'multiple vias'.

It's a pity that they use 'must' and 'should' in successive phrases below 19.1, as usually 'should' is weaker than 'must', but it still means 'do it unless you really understand why you're not'.

Comment: Strange, in figure 13, there is no via between this "ground paddle" and GND bottom layer shown. Maybe a good idea to send a support inquiry to the manufacturer.

Comment: not great is it? They say they should be there, but don't picture them.

Comment: Thanks for that @Neil_UK! Really helps me to feel more assured.

Comment: @TomKuschel, A good suggestion too. I will see what they have to say.

Comment: @TomKuschel FYI the original post has been updated with info from the manufacturer.

Comment: @Neil_UK, please see the updated post above - you were spot on!

Comment: @R. Fitz Thank you for the effort. That makes sense. I think they will update the documents soon - release/publishing processes sometimes take longer, I've my own experiences.

Comment: @R.Fitz They're still not quite consistent are they? That new diagram shows a white block labelled 'paddle', which is narrower than the green block shown under it, and consistent with the other views that show it coming right to the edge of the module. I'm usually inconsistent in the first draft of my posts, but you'd hope a supplier would be a bit more careful, espeically on a request for clarification.